# Getting camel-case alias in Laravel Eloquent select with DB::raw

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel Eloquent. I need a column's name to be in camel-case. The query looks like this:

```
IDProofDetails::select('idproof_details.idproof_id as IDNumber', 'idproof_types.lcode_id_proof_name as idProofType',
                DB::raw("ENCODE(CONVERT_TO(photo, 'UTF-8'), 'base64') as PhotoImage"))
                ->leftJoin('idproof_types', 'idproof_types.id', '=', 'idproof_details.id_proof_type_id')
                ->get();
```

Result looks like this:

```
[
  "IDNumber" => "df23redf",
  "idProofType" => "AADHAR",
  "photoimage" => null
]
```

The other 2 columns are working fine but the one inside the raw query `PhotoImage` is getting as `photoimage`. Is there any option to get it as camel-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias of "PhotoImage" can be obtained using `"photoImage"`

Now try out this

```
 IDProofDetails::select('idproof_details.idproof_id as IDNumber', 'idproof_types.lcode_id_proof_name as idProofType',
        DB::raw('ENCODE(CONVERT_TO(photo, "UTF-8"), "base64") as "photoImage"'))
            ->leftJoin('idproof_types', 'idproof_types.id', '=', 'idproof_details.id_proof_type_id')
            ->get();
```

The photoImage should come under quotes else it will taken as lower case.